# How to get Haskell Chart example1 working for Diagrams backend?

Tags: haskell, charts

The example outputs for Haskell's chart library look great. They all use the Cairo backend which I cannot install properly, so I'd like to try out the library using the Diagrams backend.

However, it is not obvious to me how to do this. In particular, `def` is undefined.

Can someone help me get started and show me how to modify the [source code for example 1](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki/example%201) so that it can run using the Diagrams backend?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chart library, but `def` is part of `Data.Default.Class`, which is one of the imports in that example. Did you forget to copy that line? If not, I think you should provide an exact error message (and code if you did more than just substitute `Diagrams` for `Cairo` in the backend import).

Comment: I took the example code verbatim, and changed the Cairo import to a Diagrams import. So, either the Cairo backend defines `def` and the Diagrams backend doesn't, or the example is incomplete.

Comment: So then by '`def` is undefined' you meant that a `Default` instance was missing? That's why I asked for the exact error.

Answer (score 3):

The problematic `def` is the `FileOptions` argument to the Cairo backend's `renderableToFile`. This has a [Default](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-class-0.0.1/docs/Data-Default-Class.html) instance.

To render with the Diagrams backend, replace the call to `renderToFile` with `renderableToSVGFile` from the [Diagrams backend](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-diagrams-1.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Backend-Diagrams.html):

```
main = renderableToSVGFile chart 800 600 "example.svg"
```