# How to properly setup Chart using Diagrams backend?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams, haskell-chart

I am trying to test [Chart](https://www.stackage.org/lts-15.10/package/Chart-1.9.3) using the [Diagrams backend](https://www.stackage.org/lts-15.10/package/Chart-diagrams-1.9.3) (both from Stackage) with this example

```hs
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Easy
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend.Diagrams

signal :: [Double] -> [(Double,Double)]
signal xs = [ (x,(sin (x*3.14159/45) + 1) / 2 * (sin (x*3.14159/5))) | x <- xs ]

test :: IO ()
test = toFile def "example1_big.png" $ do
    layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation"
    setColors [opaque blue, opaque red]
    plot (line "am" [signal [0,(0.5)..400]])
    plot (points "am points" (signal [0,7..400]))
```

from [example-1](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki/example%201) of the wiki.

In `Main.hs` file

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = test
```

The project builds and runs without any errors and does in fact produces a `example1_big.png` file in the project directory. But I cannot open it using `feh` or any other image viewer.

This is what `feh` says.

```sh
$ feh example1_big.png

feh WARNING: example1_big.png - No Imlib2 loader for that file format
feh: No loadable images specified.
See 'feh --help' or 'man feh' for detailed usage information
```

Using `mediainfo` on it shows that it doesn't have proper format information.

```sh
$ mediainfo example1_big.png
General
Complete name                            : example1_big.png
File size                                : 149 KiB
```

Looking around I did find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392233/how-to-get-haskell-chart-example1-working-for-diagrams-backend). Essentially they suggest to use a properly defined `FileOptions` instead of using `def` default.

So this is what I did

```hs
svgFileOpt :: FileOptions
svgFileOpt = FileOptions (800, 600) SVG loadCommonFonts

signal :: [Double] -> [(Double, Double)]
signal xs =
  [ (x, (sin (x * 3.14159 / 45) + 1) / 2 * (sin (x * 3.14159 / 5))) | x <- xs ]

plotDayVsDouble :: IO ()
plotDayVsDouble = toFile svgFileOpt "example1_big.png" $ do
  layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation"
  setColors [opaque blue, opaque red]
  plot (line "am" [signal [0, (0.5) .. 400]])
  plot (points "am points" (signal [0, 7 .. 400]))
```

Unfortunately results where exactly the same. I was surprised to see `mediainfo` not even showing dimensional information.

```sh
$ mediainfo example1_big.png

General
Complete name                            : example1_big.png
File size                                : 149 KiB
```

Comment: Can you try `file example1_big.png`?

Comment: `file` on both `example1_big.png` and `example1_big.svg`  shows `SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image`.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Honestly not until you mentioned that! Then I did some digging and found that instead of using just `feh` I needed to use `feh --magick-timeout 1` from `imagemagick` and things worked perfectly!

Comment: PNG and SVG are very different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `feh` and other image viewers I tried didn't support `SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image` out of the box.

Using `feh --magick-timeout 1` or `imagemagick`'s `display` worked!